# Answering a non jews question on areas forbidden to teach them

Tags: discussion

What is the policy with regard to answering an obviously non jewish questioners question about torah (explain this halacha, passage in the torah, talmud) when it is on an area forbidden to teach them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The policy is anyone who wants to post a question can post a question, and anyone who wants to post an answer can post an answer.

If for whatever reason you don't want to post an answer to a specific question, just don't. If you are unsure if you are permitted to post an answer to a specific question according to Halakha, you should ask your local rabbi for a ruling.

Comment: may be that disputation and teaching are not equals.